# A question about the incorporation of clusters in the `rake` function

Tags: r, rake, survey, weighted

my question regards an example survey that includes a first-stage cluster and the application of `survey::rake`.

```
library(survey)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(111)
mood = sample(c("happy","neutral","grumpy"),
            size = 1000,
            replace=TRUE,
            c(0.3,0.3,0.4))

set.seed(222)
sex = sample(c("female","male"),
            size=1000,
            replace=TRUE,
            c(0.6,0.4))

set.seed(333)
age_group = sample(c("young","middle","senior"),
            size=1000,
            replace=TRUE,
            c(0.2,0.6,0.2))


status = data.frame(mood=mood,
                    sex=sex,
                    age_group=age_group,
                    income = trunc(runif(1000,1000,2000)),
                    dnum = rep(c(441,512,39,99,61),each = 200),
                    fpc1 = rep(200,1000))
                      

# The source data is :

source = data.frame(mood = rep(c("happy","neutral","grumpy"),6),
                    sex = rep(rep(c("female","male"),each=3),3),
                    age_group = rep(c("young","middle","senior"),each=6),
                    Freq = c(0.0750,0.1250,0.0500,0.0750,0.1250,0.0500,0.0600,
                             0.1000,0.0400,0.0600,0.1000,0.0400,0.0165,
                             0.0275,0.0110,0.0135,0.0225,0.0090) )


# We created the total population distribution tables as follows :

targets1 = data.frame(mood = c("happy","neutral","grumpy"),
                      Freq = nrow(status)*c(sum(source$Freq[source$mood=="happy"]),
                                            sum(source$Freq[source$mood=="neutral"]),
                                            sum(source$Freq[source$mood=="grumpy"])))
targets1

targets2 = data.frame(sex = c("male","female"),
                      Freq = nrow(status)*c(sum(source$Freq[source$sex=="male"]),
                                            sum(source$Freq[source$sex=="female"])) )
targets2  

targets3 = data.frame(age_group = c("young","middle","senior"),
                      Freq = nrow(status)*c(sum(source$Freq[source$age_group=="young"]),
                                            sum(source$Freq[source$age_group=="middle"]),
                                            sum(source$Freq[source$age_group=="senior"])))
targets3



# and now we set the design unweighted and without the cluster :

unweighted = svydesign(id=~1,data=status)



# we apply the raking method :

status_raked = rake(design = unweighted,
                       sample.margins = list(~mood,~sex,~age_group),
                       population.margins = list(targets1,targets2,targets3))



# and we extract the weights (weights1) :

status$weights1 = weights(status_raked)



# now we shall set the design considering the cluster :

unweighted_clustered = svydesign(id=~dnum,
                                 data=status,
                                 fpc=~fpc1)


# we use the raking method :

status_clustered_raked = rake(design = unweighted_clustered,
                              sample.margins = list(~mood,~sex,~age_group),
                              population.margins = list(targets1,targets2,targets3))



# and we extract the weights as before (weights2) :

status$weights2 = weights(status_clustered_raked)
```

so my question is : why the weights1 and weights2 are identical eventhough we incorporated the clusters in it? Am I missing something when applying the raking method for the clustered design ?

Would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: The only place I see the cluster in your simulation code is `fpc1 = rep(200,1000)`. So it looks to me like you have one cluster with value `200`. If you only have one cluster, I wouldn't expect anything to be different.

Comment: Yeah you are right. when I changed the population size of each cluster (meaning for each dnum value I incorporated a specific value in the fpc1), it worked out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: so is this answered?